# 'Context' is not a member of 'Test_Register'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Its said my button is not a member of a context . but then i already defined it on code behind . this is my code :

```
 <%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Register.aspx.vb"     Inherits="Test_Register" %>


        <asp:Button ID="cmdSave" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="cmdSave_Click" />

        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```